# Will or Shall have?

Tags: sentence-construction

1. By this time tomorrow, I will reach my home
2. By this time tomorrow, I shall have reached my home.

Does the second statement improve the first one? What is the exact difference between them and when do we use them? Please clarify.

Comment: Definitely! First one is Future Simple while the second is Future Perfect. Future perfect states that an action will be completed at some point of time in the future. When you say "by this time tomorrow," you are referring to a future time, and thus, using simple past would be not correct.

Answer (score 1):

As with other instances of the use of "**will**" and "**shall**" for forming future tenses, the difference is *intent* versus *inevitability*, *necessity*, or *obligation*.

> I *will* reach home.

Expresses the intent, the desire, the readiness, *will*ingness for the events to develop as indicated.

> I *shall* reach home.

States the fact, essentially.  The circumstances are such that, regardless of my desire or often my actions, the future is set, the outcome is known.  Barring something extremely unusual or extraordinary, my arrival home is virtually guaranteed.

---

Now, in your question you also have Future Perfect (the second sentence).  Future Perfect does **not** require *shall*.  You can say

> I **will** have reached home.

It only says that your *intent* is *to have reached* home at some time in the future (a reference is needed in such cases).  The actual event of reaching home will take place *prior* to the time of which such a sentence speaks.  And that's the role of the Perfect tense.